# S3 - File, Compare, Delete

Tags: amazon-s3

We're moving 10 Tb of data from local storage to S3. I'm mostly automating the task using s3express.

However: the data technicians would like a tool similar to the VisaVersa 'compare' function;
The open up a GUI pane. Select files files in 'source' and 'delete if exist on target' and away they go.

They're not comfortable with CLI tools - is there a Windows-based GUI tool that can do this?

Comment: `robocopy` perhaps...?

Comment: @NathanC Robocopy supports S3?

Comment: @EEAA Granted, it needs to be mounted as a drive with something like [TnTDrive](http://tntdrive.com/) or similar, but it would work.

Comment: I should mention, for the volume of data you're having to deal with, you really ought to consider using the AWS Import/Export service. With this, you send your data to them on one or more hard disks and they handle importing into an S3 bucket of your choosing. This will almost certainly be much faster unless you have an absurdly fast internet circuit.

Comment: re: Import/Export.  I may revisit that.  Testing indicated we could get it done in three weeks.  I did not take into account a) the software was buggy and b) our process was not fully worked-out for communicating what directories are being moved and when.  The biggest roadblock is that this particular service is all hosted and getting them to 'put the data on a drive' is not easy and not cheap.  Which is one reason we're moving to S3 ...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, CloudBerry Explorer support this functionality.  Its their 'Move' option.

Moves the file from source to destination, deletes in the source.

If the file is already there, you can do the same thing, but overwrite/ignore, and delete.

[Link to Download](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/free-amazon-s3-explorer-cloudfront-IAM.aspx#)

Edit: As a sidenote, if your AWS S3 consultants aren't comfortable with command line interfaces to the AWS platform, I would question their actual knowledge of the platform.

Comment: Fair point. However, these are not consultants but our in-house 'data technicians'. Which is a grand title for a job that used to be called 'clerk' but what can you do.

Comment: In my experience, "Data technicians" primary job responsibilities revolve around following work instructions. In this case, just write up an easy-to-understand guide using your cli tool and be done with it.

Comment: Agreed, and fair point.  I misinterpreted the end user.